# Where has dictation and speech gone on Sierra?

Tags: macos, system-settings, voice-dictation

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202584 says

> Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Dictation & Speech.

I'm sure it used to be there, I've set it up in the past, but now I have Sierra, I cannot find it. Apple - system preferences - View gives me this list:

[image: meun screenshot]

and I can't see dictation there. I looked under `Accessibility`, and there is a `dictation` feature there, but this is all it says:

[image: accessibility screenshot]

and that looks different. I looked under `Siri`, and that has settings for speech output accent (it's a really awful accent, too, I can hear the quantisation, not enough bits) but not for dictation. I looked under `Sound`, and it's not there.

**Where is Dictation and Speech Preference on Sierra, please?**

Answer (score 1):

It's moved to the keyboard settings. `Apple - System Preferences - Keyboard - Dictation`.

I used the `Search` feature in `System Preferences` to find it. I didn't even know there was a search feature...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Look the picture]

As you can see the speech is in Accessibility, is the fifth option in the menu